# Rails 2.3.8: RailsKit testing breaks with error saying there is a conflict between rails 2.3.8 and non-existant rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm using the SASS RailsKit

```
   /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate': Unable to activate rspec-rails-2.6.1, because activesupport-2.3.8 conflicts with activesupport (~> 3.0), actionpack-2.3.8 conflicts with actionpack (~> 3.0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:212:in `try_activate'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:52:in `require'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
        from ./spec/controllers/../spec_helper.rb:6
        from ./spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from ./spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:1
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:134:in `run_examples'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/bin/spec:5
```

My versions of things:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10]
/opt/local/bin/ruby
gem version 1.6.0
/opt/local/bin/gem
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
rails (2.3.8)
rspec-rails (2.6.1, 1.3.4)
```

any idea what could be cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for fix this problem it's to use RVM and dedied an gemset per application

[RVM Best Pratices](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/)

rspec-rails (2.6.1) need Rails 3

```
gem uninstall rspec-rails
```